# Export data as XLS file

Tags: list-manipulation, gui-construction

```
data = WeatherData["WMO44207", "Temperature", {{1950}, {2013}}]
```

This list contains 11400 records ... date,temperature value .... I want to export all records as an XLS file. How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at the help for `Export[]`

Answer (score 1):

The way you want to `Export` `data` depends on your tastes and what you plan to do with the `XLS` file afterwards.

But as [belisarius said](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47309/how-to-tableform-convert-to-xls-file-thank-you#comment140339_47309) `Export` is your friend:

```
rawdata = WeatherData["WMO44207", "Temperature", {{2013}, {2013}}]
Export["your/Path/rawdata.xls", rawdata, "XLS"]
```

[image]

If you want to `Export` `rawdata` after making some *Mathematica* operations on it (e.g. `DateString`) you can do the following:

```
data = Thread@{DateString /@ First /@ rawdata, Last /@ rawdata}
Export["your/Path/data.xls", data, "XLS"]
```

[image]

Comment: :) ...and what is the trick to link a comment??

Comment: Click on the [timestamp](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47309/export-data-as-xls-file#comment140370_47316).

Comment: Ha! I never saw that link! Nice!

Comment: That can be useful sometimes.. :D